# How to concatenate in cell

Tags: excel

I want to concatenate two or more cell but i don't want to concatenate whole cell .Only want to take 2 or more character of 1st cell and 2 or more character of 2nd cell then concatenate them in the 3rd cell.Like..

Student Name Serial number   Address       Group      Section  Student ID

Monir         07001    Dhaka,Bangladesh    Science  B        SC001B

I want to take last three digit from the Serial number cell, if it is science from the group cell i want to take only sc and if it is arts i want to take at from the group cell and from the section cell i want to take full character ,Finally concatenate into the Student ID cell.

How do i can do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Build up what you need slowly:

- The last three digits of Serial#: =RIGHT(B2, 3)
- Create another table that maps: Science to Sc, Art to At and then use the LOOKUP function. eg =LOOKUP(D2, X2:X6, Y2:Y6), Where column X is filled with "Science, Art, etc" and Y is filled with "Sc,At, etc"
- Concatenate is =CONCATENATE()

So the final answer would look something like:

```
=CONCATENATE(LOOKUP(D2, X2:X6, Y2:Y6), RIGHT(B2,3), E2)
```

Comment: Thank you indeed .I am grateful to this kind of community/network .This will help me for next project.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT(), RIGHT() or MID() functions for extracting substrings. Use the "&" operator to concatenate. For example:

```
=RIGHT(C1,3) & LEFT(D1,2) & E1
```

Comment: Thank you indeed .I am grateful to this kind of community/network .This will help me for next project.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Excel. Programming. Hmmm.

Anyhoo, I suppose you could use the following:

```
=LEFT(E2,2) & RIGHT(B2,3) & D2
```

That gets the first two characters of E2, last three characters from B2 and D2.

Comment: Thank you indeed .I am grateful to this kind of community/network .This will help me for next project.Thank you once again.